# Plotting the behavior of the solution of six equations

Tags: plotting

I need plot the behavior of the solution of a system of six equation

In 2D I would use  `StreamPlot`.

```
StreamPlot[{Tan[y - x], 2^y - 2 Cos[Pi/3 - x]}, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}]
```

[image]

and in 3d I would use `Graphics3D`.

```
Graphics3D[sp[[2]] /. Arrow[z_]      Arrow[z /. {x_Real, y_Real} :> {Cos[x] Sin[y], Sin[y] Sin[x],  Cos[y]}], ImageSize -> 400];
Row[{sp, sp3d}, Spacer[5]]
```

However, I have six equations. How can I plot the behavior of the solution in such a case?

Any system consists of than four equations and  I can't use any one of them

Comment: You may be stuck with numerically solving the system and plotting the results of each equation independently as even 3D Streamplot are extremely difficult, and I am not sure you can do more dimensions than that.

Comment: @Awatif Can you explain what your problem is? Write down 6 equations and what you want to draw.

Comment: dx1 / dt = Vh -k1x1x6-k2x1x6-d1x1 ،
 dx2 / dt = k1x1x6 + k2x1x6- (d1 + r) x2 ،
 dx3 / dt = rx2- (d1 + r) x2 ، 
dx4 / dt = Vn-mx4 ، 
dx5 / dt = mx4x3- (d2 + l) x5 ، 
dx6 / dt = lx5-d2x6. x1 (0) = 1 ، 
x2 (0) = 0.38 ، x3 (0) = 0.02 ، x4 (0) = 3.5 ، x5 (0) = 0.12 ، x6 (0) = 0.24 
I want plot Direction of Solution